# AsyncTask's get() method's behavior changed with different API levels

Tags: android, android-asynctask, execute

My app's targetSdkVersion is 11. I need to upgrade it to 14 or upper. Unfortunately my current code heavily depends on codes like this.

```
int timeout = 5000;  
return new HttpMnagerAsync().execute().get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In targetSdkVersion 11:
This code execute the method HttpMnagerAsync()'s doInBackground() immediately and wait for 5 seconds  for complete the execution and return the results. If failed to finish in 5 seconds a timeout exception returns. (This is the expectation)

When changed to targetSdkVersion 14:
This code waits 5 seconds doing nothing, and it returned timeout exception, and then it hits the HttpMnagerAsync()'s doInBackground() method.

I need to upgrade the targetSdkVersion to 14.
any explanation is appreciated to overcode this issue.

Comment: using `AsyncTask.get` is a terrible idea ... for your sanity rewrite the code ... set the timeouts for http client and do not use `get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling get() will not make Asynctask asynchronous, get() waits for the result blocking the ui thread. Remove get() and use execute like for example:

```
new HttpMnagerAsync().execute();
```

Then, you can set your timeout in Http client, for example:

```
try
{     
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
   HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

   // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
   // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
   int timeoutConnection = 5000;
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

   // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
   // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
   int timeoutSocket = 6000;
   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
} 
catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) 
{
    //Here Connection TimeOut excepion    
    Toast.makeText(xyz.this, "Your connection timedout", 11000).show();
}
```